# How to dynamically switch between connections to many Fox Pro databases using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to connect to one of 40ish Fox Pro Databases at runtime. How can i force Entity Framework to decouple from the first data base and connect to a second. e.g there is a 2015 database and we want to connect to 2014.

Comment: throw away your datacontext and create new one with proper connectionstring? :)

Answer (score 0):

If the databases are alike then you can try tweaking the connectionstring property of Dbcontext.Database.Connection property.

Comment: is there anyway you could expand on that? I'm pretty lost with the whole thing...